# From Amsterdam Schipol to Hoofdorp?

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam

I'm going with 5 friends to Amsterdam and I would like to reach the "Papa's Beach House" (IJweg 961, 2131 LV Hoofddorp) using the public transport from Schipol. Is that possible and can be cheap?

Last time I've used the free shuttle from hotel (Bastion Hoofdorp) but I think that's not correct if this time I don't be hosted there, right?

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Schiphol+Amsterdam+Airport,+Evert+van+de+Beekstraat,+Amsterdam+Airport+Schiphol,+Netherlands/IJweg+961,+2131+LV+Hoofddorp,+Netherlands/@52.3053474,4.6821727,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c5e134e0fd162d:0xc7d51583f1cef188!2m2!1d4.7682744!2d52.3105386!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c5e63812676a2f:0xae917ed31b7ab784!2m2!1d4.674177!2d52.3234252!3e3

Comment: Use 9292.nl for public transport in the Netherlands, or just Google Maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bus line 300](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/station-schiphol-airport/hoofddorp_ijweg/departure/2016-06-08T0835#) will take you there. One-way fare is E2.40 but you'll need an "[OV Chipkaart](http://9292.nl/en/fares-and-public-transport/ov-chipkaart#)" for each member of your group (normal cards are E7.50, there are disposable cards that may be cheaper but I haven't found their price online. Or you can buy a [one-day card](http://en.gvb.nl/service-en-verkoop/reisproducten/tarieven-2016) for E7.50.

Comment: (+1) A ticket bought directly from the bus chauffeur (effectively a disposable OV-chipkaart including the fare for a 60-min trip on the Connexxion network) costs EUR 5. You will need to buy another disposable OV-chipkaart for the return trip so if there is any chance at all that you will come to the Netherlands again in the next few years, buying an anonymous OV-chipkaart for 7,50 might be a good option.

Comment: Another precisions: Disposable OV-chipkaart are never sold separately and cannot be reused. They are always sold together with a "travel product" like a day card or bus ticket.

Comment: Connexxion sometimes runs 'after 9 AM reduction' tickets. I have not seen any ads recently but you will get the reduction if it is going. (that is all people who pay cash in the bus, not when using a chip card but I bet that is cheaper for a single short ride.)

Answer (score 3):

I've found an extra way to reach this exactly address. The Courtyard (hotel) Shuttle can be booked even if I'm not sleeping there, the cost is 5.50EUR and it's from Schipol Airport directly to Courtyard Hotel that is almost inside the Papa's Beach House (IJweg 961, 2131 LV Hoofddorp)